# What Jquery plugin is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user hover overs one of the items such as Research, Brand Strategy, Audience Engagement the background colour in the bottom section changes via a inline style.

http://www.odopod.com/work/tags/strategy/

I was wondering, how it is done or which Jquery plugin they were using?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a plugin, this is done through good old plain jQuery:

```
<div class='something'>my text goes here blah blah blah</div>
<div class='somethingelse'>my background color goes here</div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.something').hover(function() {
        $(this).next('div.somethingelse').css('background-color','red');
    }, function() {
        $(this).next('div.somethingelse').css('background-color','blue');
    });
});
```

Depending on what you want you could set up the HTML in many different ways. You would then use whatever [DOM traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) function is appropriate to find the associated DIV and manipulate it's CSS accordingly.

Comment: You can't fade between two background colors using standard jQuery - you need to use a plugin for that, as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To animate a background color using jQuery, use the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plugin:

```
// global nav effect
$('#global_header li').hover(function(){
  $('div.marker',$(this)).animate({height:3}, 90)
},function(){
  if(false == $(this).hasClass('active'))
  {
    $('div.marker',$(this)).animate({height:0}, 90)
  }
})

$('#global_header li').click(function(){
  $('div.marker',$(this)).addclass('active')
})
```

That is all it does.  It uses hover() and animate().

---

Ok, so that's the script for the global header, but it does roughly the same thing, just affects a different piece.